# How do you call another process from within a process c#

Tags: c#, winforms

So basically i have an action or process on a linkedlabel called Refresh. which refreshes a drop down, but i need to then call that from another button which is basically a posting button, but then refreshes the drop down which the linked label refreshes. I think this is simple but i don't know the coding..thanks

```
    private void Refresh_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        string connetionString; SqlConnection cnn;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        cmd = new SqlCommand("exec vfpMRUFiles @exec,'365'", cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@exec", Exec.Text);
        SqlDataReader sReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sReader.Read())
        {
            string MattResult = sReader["MT05"] + " - " + sReader["MT01"];
            comboBox1.Items.Add(MattResult);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide some code snippet? is this windows forms, WPF or some other technology?

Comment: Windows forms. which part of the code would you need.

Comment: can you update the question instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

in your button Clicked event

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //just call the LinkClicked function when your button get clicked
    LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(linkLabel1, new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs(linkLabel1.Links[0], MouseButtons.Left));
}

private void LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    //your code that do the refresh
}
```

---

another way:

extract your refresh code to a method

```
private void RefreshDropDown()
{
    string connetionString; SqlConnection cnn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    cmd = new SqlCommand("exec vfpMRUFiles @exec,'365'", cnn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@exec", Exec.Text);
    SqlDataReader sReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (sReader.Read())
    {
        string MattResult = sReader["MT05"] + " - " + sReader["MT01"];
        comboBox1.Items.Add(MattResult);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
private void yourbutton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshDropDown();
}
```

Comment: @Matthew Rodwell  Please accept my answer if it's helpful